# CSS percentage widths out of document width?

Tags: html, css, width, percentage

I set a `min-width` of `1000px` on [a website I've been working on](http://barlowprogramming.github.io). In the header, the (`float`ed) links each have a percentage `width` (25%), and the `<nav>` has a full width (100%).

Right now, when the window is too small, the header and navigation bar gets cut off at the 100% window width (it doesn't expand over to the overflow area).

Is there any way (with just CSS) for the header to expand to the full *document* width (not the *window* width), and then the links to resize accordingly? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see the problem. What do you mean 'gets cut off'? The navigation breaks, but that is to be expected... If you don't want the text to break, why not make it smaller using media queries in CSS?

Comment: @Narxx I don't want the navigation to break. The `<nav>` bar gets gut short at the end of the window, but I want it to expand past there. It's a temporary solution before I make a mobile site (with media queries)

Comment: Why don't you give the header the same width properties as the content? `calc(100% + 80px)` ? Personally, I don't understand why you do this, it doesn't make sense to me, but if you want the two parts to have the same width, and you change one of them manually, change the other as well...

Comment: The content is positioned like that so that it fills up the full with with a `40px` margin on both sides. I want the header to fill up the whole *document* width.

Comment: Full width AND 40 pixels margin? That doesn't make sense to me. Either you want full width, or 40px margin. You can give it media queries to have inner margins on desktop resolutions, and full width on mobile, but I wouldn't use 100% + 80px as width to achieve that. It will create scrolling, and it's bad.

Comment: @Narxx It works when the window is wider than 1000px, but it is not dynamic. It does not create scrolling. Check for yourself.

Comment: Yes, but this is only because you have `min-width: 1000px` on your `body` element. If you remove that, you won't have scrolling at all....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107540/discussion-between-narxx-and-jonathan-lam).

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for. Percentage widths inherit from the viewport, ultimately. An HTML document does not have an inherent width.

Comment: @TylerH That answers my question. I guess there isn't a way to do it.

Comment: @JonathanLam If you know exactly how big you want your page to be, you can set the width in pixels on the `html` element. But that's about all you can do.

Comment: @TylerH I was thinking about doing something like that dynamically using JS

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap all the data **(like: header,#container,footer)** inside of wrapper div **`<div id="wrapper"></div>`**, remove padding-top property from the body and use below mentioned css

```
#wrapper{padding-top: 150px;position: relative;}
```